# How can I display data from 3 tables into a single table?

Tags: excel, data-visualization

I have 3 datasets a,b,c and 3 tables that give values based on the strength of their relationships. a has 5 items, b has 7 items, and c has 4 items. (a,b)(a,c)(b,c). I am trying to find a way to display all the data from these tables in a single graphic. The axis would have a Y shape with each leg representing a different data set and the cells representing their relationship strength.

I have looked through excel charts and haven't found anything that might help represent this. Is there another program which would be better? Looking for something simple to use.

Below is an example of the 3 tables and the type of data they contain. I want a way to show the scores for each relationship in a grid.

Table 1

| A | B | Score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | x | 3 |
| 2 | x | 5 |
| 3 | x | 0 |
| 1 | y | 2 |
| 2 | y | 6 |
| 3 | y | 0 |
| 1 | z | 5 |
| 2 | z | 8 |
| 3 | z | 0 |

Table 2

| A | C | Score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | blue | 3 |
| 2 | blue | 8 |
| 3 | blue | 2 |
| 1 | red | 0 |
| 2 | red | 4 |
| 3 | red | 1 |
| 1 | yellow | 3 |
| 2 | yellow | 3 |
| 3 | yellow | 9 |

Table 3

| B | C | Score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| x | blue | 2 |
| x | red | 1 |
| x | yellow | 5 |
| y | blue | 0 |
| y | red | 3 |
| y | yellow | 7 |
| z | blue | 0 |
| z | red | 1 |
| z | yellow | 3 |

[Here is an example of what I am trying to do with the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJjzM.png)

[I manually created this type of visual in autoCAD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kr135.png)

This works as a one-off but it doesn't scale and is very tedious. Hoping there is a programmatic way to create something similar.

Comment: Use the common item between the tables.

Comment: @SolarMike that works if there are 2 tables, but in this case there are 3. Each table has one column in common with each other table, but they are different. I want it to look like a Y shape or a peace sign.

Comment: Then you need to show some example data so it is explained clearly.

Comment: @SolarMike thanks for the feedback. I've added sample tables to show what it looks like

Comment: Please share expected results and what you have tried so far...

Comment: @Birel updated with a sample image

Comment: @Corosis, I see the problem you're facing - there is no relation between these 3 tables, making it difficult to get a combined result. Are there no other columns you can add to the tables, making it possible to get a relationship between the 3? That way you can accomplish the combined result by using these columns to create a relationship between the tables... etc.

Comment: @Birel so far I have manually drawn the grid in autoCAD and then pasted in the values. This works as a one-off but it's very tedious and wouldn't scale at all. I was hoping there was something in excel or another program which could generate it for me. I am sure I will need to do similar visuals in the future with more data. I will attach a ss of the autoCAD drawing.

Comment: You can use excels' power query to "merge" the data.  First define each dataset from a table/range.  Then "merge" them in power query to create an expanded table containing the Table1.A = Table2.A and Table1.B=Table3.B  given data listed, that would result in 81 rows.  I leave teh graphing up to you...